# How to track the data after scanning in zxing QR code library?

Tags: android

I am making a online app in which I have develope QR code scanner by using zxing library.Now,It is saving the data in the history and generated its own database.

But I want to generate my own database and after scanning whatever will be the data I want to store that in my table.

But I am unable to do that.

Please suggest me some way to do it.I am new to android and I got stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to make database in android?

Comment: yes i know to make database in android

Comment: Then what is the problem, Insert the result into database and retrieve the same.

Comment: Actually I m not getting how to insert the scan result by QR code to my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frame_scan"
                        android:layout_width="150dip"
                        android:layout_height="100dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                        <include layout="@layout/capture" />
                    </FrameLayout>
```

Add the above xml piece of code in your main.xml and extend the CaptureActivity as following :

```
public class ScanCard extends CaptureActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_card);
}

if you using zxing as a library and extend the CaptureActivity, you will get the result as follows :

    @Override
    public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleDecode(rawResult, barcode);
         
        Toast.makeText(
                ScanCard.this,
                "Results : "
                        + rawResult.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

         
    }
```

}

--

// Get the scanned values from the above method and save that in the database as follows :

```
MultiMediaDB mDB = new MultiMediaDB();
mDB.open();
```

--

Your insertion code to the database :

say for ex :

```
mDB.insertMediaURL("scanned results");
mDB.close();
```

and don't forget to close the db as well. Else it may throw illegal state exception

Here is the simple database class with a value.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MultiMediaDB {

public static final String PHOTO_URL = "photo";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private final Context mCtx;
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private static final String TAG = "Multimedia DB ";

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MultiMediaDB.db";
// Multimedia table name
private static final String MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE = "MultiMediaTable";

private static final String CREATE_MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE if not exists "
        + MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE
        + "("
        + KEY_ID
        + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
        + PHOTO_URL
        + " TEXT "
        + ")";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public MultiMediaDB(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public MultiMediaDB open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDbName(Context ctx) {
    return mDb;
}

// Delete all the candidates
public boolean deleteAllCandidates() {
    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE, null, null);
    Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;
}

// Fetching all the candidates from the database
public Cursor fetchAllCandidates() {
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            PHOTO_URL }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

// Deleting single candidate
public void deleteSingleRow(int row_id) {
    mDb.delete(MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(row_id) });
}

// Get All PHOTO_URL :

public Cursor getAllPhotURL(String string) {

    Cursor mCursor = null;
    mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT  " + PHOTO_URL + "  FROM "
            + MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE, null);
    return mCursor;
}

// Check the database for the photo url available in database.

public boolean isPhotoAvailable(String photoUrl) {
    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + PHOTO_URL + " FROM "
            + MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE + " WHERE " + PHOTO_URL + " = " + "'"
            + photoUrl + "'", null);
    if (c.getCount() == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public long insertMediaURL(String mPhotURL) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(PHOTO_URL, mPhotURL);
    Log.d("The Values are ", " Inserted" + mPhotURL);
    return mDb.insert(MUTLIMEDIA_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
}
```

Let me know if there is any issues

Comment: actually my database is of 1 row and 1 column.And I need to scan only the product ID.I want to know that after scanning whatever data we want can be get in the method handleDecode()..?.. as I m searching this from past two days.:(

Comment: Are you using zxing's code as a separate library or you wrapped all the code in your app? Please use zxing scanner as a separate library and extend the captureActivity in your library, so that you can change your UI as well. 

And Yes, HandleDecode() method will get you the scanned results

Comment: I m using Zxing scanner as separate library.If I want to get scan data in another activity not in capture activity then what I have to do?..then also I have to extend captureActivity?

Comment: Sir,But when I extending the CaptureActivity in my new Activity then its giving error.

Comment: Actually sir in my application zxing library is in another source folder and the activity which I am created is in another source folder .Thats why its giving me error and saying to create captureActivity. How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting result like this in your activity

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
        // handle scan result, Save result in database 'result.getText().toString();'
      }
      // else continue with any other code you need in the method
      ...
    }
```